# How to remove empty space from my Bootstrap grid columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a search filter with input fields for search term, two datepickers and two buttons:

```
<div id="search-holder">
    <div id="search-box">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9 form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input id="searchResident" type="text" class="form-control search-input col-md-10" data-bind="value: mainDataSearchWorker, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: mainDataRefreshData" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchNurse" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="searchIntakeDateFrom" type="text" class="form-control search-date pointer picker" data-bind="datePicker: mainDataSearchDateFrom, maxDate: mainDataSearchDateTo, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: mainDataRefreshData" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchDateFrom" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    <input id="searchIntakeDateTo" type="text" class="form-control search-date pointer picker" data-bind="datePicker: mainDataSearchDateTo, minDate: mainDataSearchDateFrom, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: mainDataRefreshData" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchDateTo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 form-group row">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-newline" data-bind="click: function() {mainDataRefreshData()}"> @SharedResources.Index.Search</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm leftmargin10" title="@SharedResources.Index.Reset" data-bind="click: function() {mainDataResetSearch()}">
                        <span class="fa fa-repeat"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the input field for searchterm "searchResident" doesn't fully stretch and I have empty space in between the input field and datepicker field:

[image]

How do I fully stretch the "searchResident" input field so I don't have empty space in between the input elements?

https://www.bootply.com/EAkJ1KHlla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <input id="searchResident" type="text" class="form-control search-input 
**col-md-10**" data-bind="value: mainDataSearchWorker, valueUpdate: 
'afterkeydown', enterkey: mainDataRefreshData"placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchNurse">
```

Your input has a **col-md-10** class which set a max width of 83% of its container.

Change it to **col-md-12** and it would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1) You're giving the input a 10-column width with `col-md-10`, thus your main problem. Give it the full 12 columns.

2) You're not nesting any of the columns properly since you're sometimes using the columns as rows or sometimes not even adding a new row at all. As in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting), you need to create a new row below the parent column and only put the nested columns inside the new row. The example from the documentation:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    Level 1: .col-sm-9
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-4 .col-sm-6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```